# How to show PHP curl progress with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, curl, cakephp-2.0

I'm writing a PHP web app using the [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) framework (v2.x). On one of my views there is a form which uploads a big video file to a 3rd party API. The files are big, so the upload can easily take a minute or two. So I'm submitting the form with AJAX and showing the user a dancing hippo (or whatever) so they know the wheels are still turning. Here's that script, which uses the [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/):

```
<script>
var options = {
    //complete : callback_function...,
    //error : callback_function...,
    beforeSend : function() {
        $("#MediaSubmitForm").hide();
        $("#MediaSubmitForm").after('<img class="hula-hippo" src="/img/hippo-hula.gif" />');

    },
    success : function(data){
        $(".hula-hippo").hide();
        $("#MediaSubmitForm").after("<h3>Upload complete!</h3>");
        console.log(data);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete){
        console.log(percentComplete);
    }

};
$("#MediaSubmitForm").ajaxForm(options);
</script>
```

In order to not expose our API key to the client, I submit the form to a controller action, which makes the actual POST request from the server to the API using curl. Here is that method (and one callback).

```
//uploads a video to a project through the API
public function apiUpload( $tmp_filename, $project_hashed_id ) {
    $api_password = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $username = 'api';
    $data = array(
        'api_password'  => $api_password,
        'file'          => '@'.$tmp_filename,
        'project_id'    => $project_hashed_id
        );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://upload.wistia.com" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, array($this, 'apiUploadCallback'));  
    $result = curl_exec($ch); //***Note A***
    curl_close($ch);
    return( json_decode($result) );

}

//BE CAREFUL... PHP 5.5 Added the cURL resource as the first argument to the CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION callback 
protected function apiUploadCallback( $total_bytes_down_expected, $bytes_down_so_far, $total_bytes_up_expected, $total_bytes_up_so_far ) {
    if ($total_bytes_up_expected > 0)
        //error_log( round( ($total_bytes_up_so_far / $total_bytes_up_expected)*100) );
        echo ( round( ($total_bytes_up_so_far / $total_bytes_up_expected)*100) ); //***Note B***
}
```

This works, but it would be **much** better if I could show the user the actual progress of the upload. I've figured out how to calculate this with the callback function (see `***Note B***`), but I'm not sure how to pass it back to the page (where the user is waiting). I tried using jQuery's `uploadProgress` but it shows the progress of the file uploading to our server... *NOT* the progress of the upload to the API. I tried echoing the progress from the curl callback (`***Note B***`) but it spits out a series of numbers which tangle with the json object returned by the api (`***Note A***`), which I also need. Something like this:

```
11112222233344444...9898989899999999999999{api:"response mixed in here"}100100100100
```

How can I capture the curl progress AND the subsequent API response?

Comment: Could you make another ajax call to check the progress? use timeout to repeatedly poll for the progress until completion.

Comment: That's an interesting idea but I'd like to hear more of what you're thinking. For example, are you thinking two ajax calls to two different places? Or two ajax calls to the same controller... the first handles the progress, and the second finds the json object.

Comment: I was thinking of two calls to different controllers (I'm not familiar with Cake TBH) you could perhaps store the progress in a session variable and use setTimeout to poll until progress was 100%

Comment: Interesting idea about stashing the progress in a session variable. I guess then the uploadProgress callback would just ping that repeatedly until it's done. I might give that a try.

Comment: I experimented with storing the progress in a session variable. Long story short: it's very tricky because PHP locks the session file. So simultaneous access gets queued and the second call(s) trying to read the session have to wait until after the download finishes (defeating the point). Apparently the locking behavior can be manipulated, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Can you please tell how you show progress bar in jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can store progress status in user`s session and then use ajax to get information from session then show it on page

Comment: See my comment under the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the status on the server using AJAX and let it call every amount of time. But that will spam your server unnecessary, it takes every time a new HTTP request. I'll advise you using a web socket. Than you build an connection directly between server and browser so you server could send directly an update of the progress when it happened to the browser.

Comment: Web sockets will eventually be the solution to this kind of thing, but browser support isn't there yet and I need something that can go into production now.

Comment: @Emerson The latest versions of all browser, have support at the moment. [link](http://caniuse.com/websockets), of course you could make a fall back for if the browser doesn't support and than use AJAX instead.

Comment: Thanks Hugo. The project we're building has to support IE8+ as well as several versions back for the rest. So I guess the follow-up question is: What's the fallback?

Comment: I would let the apiUploadCallback function write the progress into a file where the filename correspond to the users session. Let the users browsers make an AJAX call to your server to a PHP-file to read the file or just directly to the file and let JavaScript do the rest.

Comment: I actually tried that and it worked... But (for anyone else wanting to try this) you have to remember something important: that progress file needs to be unique for *every* user. Otherwise multiple users at the same time will be see crazy data from other users. The way I did it was by creating/prefixing the file name with the current users session id. You also should remember to delete that file on completion so you don't end up with a million progress log files. I have no idea whether this approach would be stable in production.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Moshen says :

> You can store progress status in user`s session and then use ajax to
>   get information from session then show it on page

but don't forget to call 'session_write_close()'

```
$nPourcent = round(($total_bytes_up_so_far / $total_bytes_up_expected)*100);

session_start();
$_SESSION['progress'] = $nPourcent;
session_write_close();
```